# Serverless approach to archive incoming JSON blobs?

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm considering building a serverless web API which uses API Gateway to receive a stream of JSON blobs. I'd like to archive every incoming blob (after some basic authentication and validation of course). What are your recommendations on how to do this?

Additional info:

- I'm using AWS Lambda reduce cost.
- The archives will be accessed very infrequently, so I've been eyeballing S3 Glacier to reduce pricing. My issue is I need to figure out how to do batching of blobs per S3 file to avoid the overhead of many files.
- Alternative storage services that I've been looking at are Cloudwatch logs and DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Great question, I'll post my possible solution. Also is it possible to list more requirements, what load are you expecting, what benchmark you try to achieve etc? Is the Glacier the service you want to use because retrieving data from there takes quite a bit time and is expensive (Do some calculations based on the data amount you have)?

I would split this task into two different AWS Lambda functions:

- First Lambda receives the JSON and saves it into S3 as plain text file.
- Now setup the Cloudwatch alert, based on the items save into bucket or the size(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html). The alert is triggering the next lambda archive function. Let's say the alert is executed after 30MB of data is received.
- The archive function job is to take the S3 bucket content but together the zip/tar package, remove archived files and move archive into next S3 bucket/Glacier.